# Python won't write each time new lines into text file

Tags: python, text, lines

I have two python files, both of them in the same folder. The main file executes the whole function, making my program what I want it to do. The other file writes data to a text file.
However, there's one issue with writing data to the text file: instead of writing each time new lines to the existing text, it completely overwrites the whole file.

### File responsible for writing data(writefile.py)

```
import codecs
def start(text):
        codecs.open('D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python342\\passguess.txt', 'a', 'utf-8')
        with open('D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python342\\passguess.txt', 'w') as file:
                file.write(text + '\n')
```

I've tried out couple of things such as .join(text) or running the code from writefile.py in the main file. Nothing seems to work..

Comment: Forgot to add: the start function is executed more than once, thus the start function should write new lines each time with new content.

Comment: You have to use `'a'` mode when you open the file to append to it. You are using `'w'`. Also, what is that first `codecs.open` supposed to do?

Comment: @tobias_k sets the file encoding to utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with the line

```
with open('D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python342\\passguess.txt', 'w') as file:
```

this one opens the file in write mode, to append you want 'a' option so just change to

```
with open('D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python342\\passguess.txt', 'a') as file:
```

and you should be fine

Comment: Also, it probably should be `with codecs.open(..., 'a', 'utf-8') as ...`, otherwise that other lines does not make much sense.

Comment: I have no idea what the codec.open line does or what sense it makes, but the `with open`line will overwrite the file as it stands with the w option.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But why? 
I thought 'a' does create a new file as 'a' stands for 'add' and later to open the file for writing it should be 'w'?

Comment: Here is where I end up constantly when I forget about the exact write modes. ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036/870769. (also see the links to the BSD and Python 3 docs there).

Comment: @sthzg: Thank you :) That's some nice info, will add that link to my favs!